# Decoding encrypted crypto data fetched from Rest API with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, cryptography, decode, cryptocurrency

I am currently looking into different types of historical crypto data and I'm curious to extract some interesting data from the API endpoints of the following website:

https://data.hyblockcapital.com/huobilsa?symbol=XBT&resolution=1&from=1688916548&to=1689003128&indicator=HUOBITTLSA

However, instead of getting a human-readable object, the following long string of encrypted code is returned:

> 807abb676f2013a8976c04117a1db93f403a8733c071ca46769a0e1863163bf12f4f51bed72c2d9372bdf94566b6181d2q0fqkwNJyVHgrfD7720TcQ2AbolM5xUBNDdv........

The string is extremely long and therefore I use ........ to denote the remaining characters. A sensible way to decode the string would be to use the following decoding package in Python:

```
import base64
base64.b64decode(.....the above string.....)
```

However, the result upon decoding is still in a non-human readable form as follows:

> b'\xf3N\xdam\xbe\xbb\xe9\xfd\xb4\xd7v\xbc\xf7\xbe\x9c\xd3\x8du\xed\xad]o\xdd\xdf\xe3M\xda\xf3\xbd\xf7sN\xf5q\xae:\xef\xafZ\xd1\xed|\xeb}z\xdd\xb7\xf5\xd9\xfe\x1f\xe7V\xdew\xbd\x9c\xd9\xdfw\xeff\xdd\x7f\xde9\xeb\xa6\xfa\xd7\xcd]\xda\xad\x1f\xaaL\r'%G\x82\xb7\xc3\xef\xbd\xb4M\xc46\x01\xba%3\x9cT\x04\xd0\xdd\xbe]}........

Does anyone have any ideas on the decoding? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: When I decode the base64 strings it shows an encrypted content that cannot be read. It could be TLS, AES, RSA who knows, without an decryption key you are out of luck